# objective-c google maps delegate method reverseGeocodeCoordinate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm not sure if this is new with google maps but I think it looks like this version of Google Maps for iOS already has a reverse geocoding method...one which I can't really figure out how to use.  [In their documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#camera_position), under section Camera Position, they have a function, but it doesn't look like the one that came with the SDK...or maybe there's something I don't understand here.  Can someone help out?  Here's the function that comes up in XCode:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate 
    completionHandler:(GMSReverseGeocodeCallback)handler{}
```

How can I use that if I have my coordinates in an array?  How do I get the address and country and all the possible results?

By the way, this is what they have...how does it compare:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)cameraPosition {
id handler = ^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if (error == nil) {
  GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result = response.firstResult;
  GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:cameraPosition.target];
  marker.title = result.addressLine1;
  marker.snippet = result.addressLine2;
  marker.map = mapView;
}
};
[geocoder_ reverseGeocodeCoordinate:cameraPosition.target completionHandler:handler];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse * response, NSError *error){
    for(GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result in response.results){
        NSLog(@"addressLine1:%@", result.addressLine1);
        NSLog(@"addressLine2:%@", result.addressLine2);
    } 
}];
```